# Convert special character "Ⓡ" and "®"

Tags: php, html-entities

I want to convert "Ⓡ" and "®" to readable. Currently when i using

```
htmlEntities($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'ISO-8859-1')
```

, it show great and readable in my development(Laptop/Window). But when i set this in production server (Centos), it didn't show the symbol. I'm using php 5.5.14 for both.

Comment: "*to readable*" can't you read @zerkms :-)

Comment: @Dagon: now it indeed makes sense, thank you ;-D

Comment: Its impossible to know your servers config differences between dev/prod, but generally just stick to utf-8 encodings. Set headers like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling PHP that the `$text` string is encoded in ISO-8859-1.  Are you sure that's true?  Depending on where you obtained that string from, it may be using the system's default encoding, which can vary from machine to machine and is probably UTF-8 on a CentOS system.

Look carefully at wherever you're getting that string from, and see if you can force it to always be UTF-8, regardless of the system's default encoding.  (UTF-8 is preferable since it can represent any character in Unicode; ISO-8859-1 can't.)

If you're careful to keep all your strings in a consistent, known encoding, you can avoid needing to call `htmlentities` at all.  Just use the `Content-Type` header's `charset` parameter to tell the browser what encoding the response is in (e.g. UTF-8) and it'll understand the characters.

BTW, the "Ⓡ" symbol (U+24C7 CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R) doesn't exist in ISO-8859-1.  Only "®" (U+00AE REGISTERED SIGN) does.  (You probably want to use the latter anyway, though.)